# Pybind11 for cpp extention with CGAL while Segment fault

Tags: c++, cgal, pybind11

I tried to my python script in which CGAL is used to get delaunay triangulation with pybind 11 for cpp extention. I attach each vertex with extra info as index, and I use the operation of vertex modifying. As i try to run the python script to output all  current vertex, the segement fault occurs. Any idea why and how to solve it?

```
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_3_to_face_graph.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh/IO/PLY.h>

#include <CGAL/compute_average_spacing.h>

#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

#include "utils/vec_math.h"

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned int, K> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<Vb> Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<K, Tds> Triangulation;

typedef K::FT FT;
typedef CGAL::Parallel_if_available_tag Concurrency_tag;

typedef Triangulation::Cell_handle Cell_handle;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
typedef Triangulation::Locate_type Locate_type;
typedef Triangulation::Point Point;

typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point> Surface_mesh;

class TetrahedraBuilder {
public:
    TetrahedraBuilder();
    ~TetrahedraBuilder();

    void add_points(size_t num_points, float3 *points);
    void delete_points(size_t num_points, unsigned int *index);
    void move_points(size_t num_points, unsigned int *index, float3 *point);

    std::vector<float3> export_points_idx();

private:
    std::unordered_map<size_t, Vertex_handle> idx_to_vertex;
    Triangulation delaunay_tetra;
    unsigned int cur_size = 0;
};

/* implementation is shown below */
TetrahedraBuilder::TetrahedraBuilder() {
    idx_to_vertex == std::unordered_map<size_t, Vertex_handle>();
    delaunay_tetra = Triangulation();
    cur_size = 0;
}

TetrahedraBuilder::~TetrahedraBuilder() {
}

void TetrahedraBuilder::add_points(size_t num_points, float3 *points) {
    /* add  points sequentially */
    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++) {
        auto p = Point(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].z);
        auto vertex_handle = delaunay_tetra.insert(p);
        vertex_handle->info() = cur_size;
        idx_to_vertex[cur_size] = vertex_handle;
        cur_size++;
    }
}

void TetrahedraBuilder::delete_points(size_t num_points, unsigned int *index) {
    /* delete some points, but retain the squential index of the remains */
    // TODO：May be optimized
    std::unordered_set<unsigned int> uset(index, index + num_points);
    size_t new_size = 0;
    for  (int i = 0; i < cur_size; i++) {
        if (uset.find(i) == uset.end()) {
            auto vertex_handle = idx_to_vertex[i];
            vertex_handle->info() = new_size;
            idx_to_vertex[new_size] = vertex_handle;
            new_size++;
        }
    }
    cur_size = new_size;
}

void TetrahedraBuilder::move_points(size_t num_points, unsigned int *index, float3 *point) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++) {
        auto vertex_handle = idx_to_vertex[index[i]];
        const auto p = Point(point[i].x, point[i].y, point[i].z);
        auto rt_vhandle = delaunay_tetra.move_if_no_collision(vertex_handle, p);
        if (rt_vhandle != vertex_handle) {
            std::cout << "There is a point already located in the target position!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
std::vector<float3> TetrahedraBuilder::export_points_idx() {
    std::vector<float3> result(cur_size);
    float *result_float = reinterpret_cast<float*>(result.data());
    std::cout<<"hello in here 1!" << std::endl;

    // size_t i = 0;
    for (auto vertex_handle : delaunay_tetra.all_vertex_handles()) {
        
        const auto point = vertex_handle->point();
        // result_float[vertex_handle->info()] = make_float3(point.x(), point.y(), point.z());
        const unsigned int i = vertex_handle->info();
        std::cout<<"hello in index " << i << std::endl;
        result_float[i * 3 + 0] = point.x();
        result_float[i * 3 + 1] = point.y();
        result_float[i * 3 + 2] = point.z();
    }
    return result;
}
```

And this is part of my py_bing.cpp

```
struct PyTetrahedraBuilder {
public:
    PyTetrahedraBuilder() {
        builder = std::make_unique<TetrahedraBuilder>();
    }

    ~PyTetrahedraBuilder() {
        builder.reset();
    }
    void add_points(const torch::Tensor &points) {
        CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(points);
        CHECK_CPU(points);
        CHECK_FLOAT(points);
        TORCH_CHECK(points.dim() == 2 && points.size(1) == 3, "points must have shape [num_points, 3]");    // [num_points, 3]
        builder->add_points(
            points.numel() / 3,
            reinterpret_cast<float3 *>(points.data_ptr()));
    }
    torch::Tensor export_points_idx() {
        // std::cout<<"hello 1!" << std::endl;
        std::vector<float3> points = builder->export_points_idx();
        // std::cout<<"hello 2!" << std::endl;
        if (points.size() >= (size_t)std::numeric_limits<int>::max) {
            throw Exception("Too many points!");
        }
        // for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        //     std::cout<< i <<": " << points[i].x << " " << points[i].y << " " << points[i].z << std::endl;
        // }
        auto points_out = torch::empty({(long)points.size(), 3}, torch::dtype(torch::kFloat32).device(torch::kCPU));
        memcpy(
            points_out.data_ptr(),
            reinterpret_cast<void *>(points.data()),
            points.size() * sizeof(float3));
        return points_out;
    }
PYBIND11_MODULE(dynamic_tetra_cpp_extension, m) {
    py::class_<PyTetrahedraBuilder>(m, "TetrahedraBuilder")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("add_points", &PyTetrahedraBuilder::add_points)
        .def("export_points_idx", &PyTetrahedraBuilder::export_points_idx);
}
```

The python script i run is quite simple

```
import numpy as np
import torch 
import trimesh


from utils.extension import TetrahedraTracer, TetrahedraBuilder

tetra_build = TetrahedraBuilder()

points = torch.rand(100, 3)
tetra_build.add_points(points)

vertices = tetra_build.export_points_idx()
print(vertices)
```

And the output is

```
hello in here 1!
hello in index 678559744
[1]    1369488 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python test_cpp_extension.py
```

it seems that `const unsigned int i = vertex_handle->info();` get a wrong number rusulting array out of bounds. But how it could be?
What is more strange is that it occasionally runs well but most time is segment fault!

Comment: did you try replacing `all_vertex_handles()` with `finite_vertex_handles()`?

Comment: Oh yeah! replacing `all_vertex_handles()` with `finite_vertex_handles()` did solve the problem! and i notice that the first element of the list returned by `all_vertex_handles()` contains no meanful info, which is a huge int resulting array out of bounds.